# Crosshair scatterplot chart possible with ExtJS/Raphael?

Tags: charts, extjs4, graphael

I would like to create a scatter chart and use crosshairs, like this:

[image]

Is it possible to move the y axis over to the right?

Answer (score 0):

The Ext.chart.Chart is an Ext.draw.Component so it is possible to add sprites to its surface this way at store load event

```
var chart = this.down('chart');
var vlinesprite = { /* vertical line sprite config */ },
    hlinesprite = { /* horizontal line sprite config */ };
chart.surface.add([vlinesprite, hlinesprite]);
```

Now you have to prepare the sprites to draw lines. I guess it's gonna be path sprites.